# Shorthand to test controller with only SOQL query across multiple objects?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I created a SOQL query that references fields across 3 objects, each of which has many required fields.

When testing a controller that fetches a subset of the data contained within multiple objects, is there a shorthand approach to writing tests that avoids having to initialize all of these fields when creating test records?

For reference, an anonymized sample is below:

```
public class summaryController {

    public Id accId {get; set;}
    public List<Summary_Record__c> summary {get; set;}

    public summaryController() {
        accId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().Get('id');
        summary = [SELECT Id, Name, Year__r.Name, Summary_Record_Type__c,
                          Year__r.ID_Number__r.Name, Year__r.Site__r.Name,
                          Val_Summary__r.Name, Val_Summary__r.Value__c
                     FROM Summary_Record__c 
                    WHERE Year__r.Site__r.Id = :accId 
                 ORDER BY Year__r.Name DESC];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the fields aren't populated, the query can't return all the results you've asked for. When that happens, you'll get null pointers if you try to access the ones you're queried for. The missing required fields will prevent you from inserting the records to even be able to query for them. The only alternative would be to use CSV data saved as static resource that you then use `test.loaddata()` to insert for use in your unit test.

Unless your data is complicated to create, it's typically preferred to create it programmatically rather than having your test class be dependent on the existence of a static resource. If you have many test classes that use similar data like this, the thing to do is create a utility class that creates records for those objects. That will greatly simplify your life.

Comment: test.loaddata() isn't something I'd encountered before, so +1 for educating me on that

Comment: @RobCowell See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_load_data.htm for more on `Test.loadData()`.

Comment: Also `TestSetup ` allows a single method to populate all data for an entire test class. You can put a method in a utility class then use a single line TestSetup to call the utility method to reuse across classes

Comment: Not what I was hoping for, but a good answer. Thanks @crmprogdev.